# Where to put event listeners.?

Tags: java, user-interface, event-handling, subclass

Which of these is better and why?
In my uneducated opinion, it is better to have them in separate files, because if you have, say, 10 buttons, 5 combo boxes and a list or two having all these classes in the one file will get messy. Am I right in thinking that? Why would you choose one over the other?

SimpleGUI.java:

```
public class simpleGUI extends JFrame {

public JButton button;
public JLabel label;
public simpleGUI() {
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
JPanel panel = new JPanel();
label = new JLabel("123abc");
button = new JButton("click me");

    simpleEventListener c = new simpleEventListener();
    c.setParams(label);
    button.addActionListener(c);

    panel.add(button);
    panel.add(label);

    contentPane.add(panel);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(300,300);
    setTitle("simpleGUI");
    setVisible(true);
}
public static void main(String[]args) {
    JFrame frame = new simpleGUI();
}
}
```

**simpleEventListener.java:**

```
 public class simpleEventListener implements ActionListener {
        private JLabel label;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Hello World!");
        }
        public void setParams(JLabel label) {
            this.label = label;
        }
    }
```

**or:**

```
public class simpleGUI extends JFrame {
    public JButton button;
    public JLabel label;
    public simpleGUI() {
        Container contentPane = getContentPane();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        label = new JLabel("123abc");
        button = new JButton("click me");

        simpleEventListener c = new simpleEventListener();
        button.addActionListener(c);

        panel.add(button);
        panel.add(label);

        contentPane.add(panel);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(300,300);
        setTitle("simpleGUI");
        setVisible(true);
    }
    public class simpleEventListener implements ActionListener {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            label.setText("Hello World!");
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[]args) {
        JFrame frame = new simpleGUI();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> it is better to have them in separate files, because if you have, say, 10 buttons, 5 combo boxes and a list or two having all these classes in the one file will get messy. Am I right in thinking that?

No. There's nothing really messy about it.
The file containing the class will be structured,
with a main class and several other classes in it,
that are not accessible from anywhere else but the class.

> Why would you choose one over the other?

Encapsulation.
If the listeners will not be used for any other class in your project,
then there's no need to expose them. In fact, exposing them (making them visible) is what can be messy.
Other code using your main class will also see the listener classes,
even though they cannot use them for anything.

Even when you keep the classes as inner, for example as you did `simpleEventListener`,
you should make it `private` instead of `public`.
Other classes in the project don't need to know about it.
Encapsulation goes hand in hand with information hiding.
It keeps your interfaces clean.